(Google Map) Download specific region of map for offline usages
I am developing a android app in which I want to integrate the download offline map like your google map(default app of google map).
And after download complete show in list.
When User click on any downloaded file it will show on map and redirect to the that location.
I have read number of article but all are out of dated and not give me proper code and solution.
I have tried a lot of examples like :

Google Maps offline Mode on Android Application

TileProvider using local tiles


